# Crear un AAB en visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, packages

He creado "una pequeña" app en xamarin con vs2022.
Pero no puedo o no encuentro como generar un .AAB en vs2022, solo .APK
Alguna idea de como crear .AAB

Comment: .net maui genera los aab

Comment: El proyecto debe ser .NET MAUI y automáticamente lo genera como .AAB. Si tu app es de Xamarin deberás convertirla a MAUI.